# Passing string with single quotes to PostgreSQL procedure called with Sequelize causes 500 error

Tags: json, postgresql, sequelize.js, escaping, procedure

I'm trying to call a PostgreSQL procedure via Sequelize like so:

```
const reqObj = JSON.stringify({
  'id': 54,
  'name': 'my_key',
  'note': "the driver's position"
});

const results = await sequelize.query(
  `call app.my_procedure(:reqObj, 0)`, 
  { 
    raw: true,
    replacements: { reqObj }, 
    type: QueryTypes.SELECT, logging: console.log }
);
```

As you can notice, the `note` field is a string that contains a single quote.

When I run the code I get a 500 error with the message: `invalid input syntax for type numeric: "syntax error at or near "position""`

By logging the query I can notice that the single quote has been escaped as follow:

```
Executing (default): call app.my_procedure('{"id":"54","name":"my_key", "note":"the driver''s position"}', 0)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

---

Actually I found out the problem was a bug in the procedure. Thank you all!

Comment: I don't believe the error you are posting can be right. Copy & paste error? You have a missing double-quote before `note` which would be an error.

Comment: `select '{"id":54,"name":"my_key","note":"the driver''s position"}'` works just fine